# Ignore directive on page load

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have setup the below directive to give focus to the 'newest' input field that is added to my page. This works perfectly other than one problem. On page load the last input on the page is selected. I want this directive to be ignored on page load so I can instead set focus on a button with the `#new-query` id. Is there anyway to tell this directive to only begin watching the scope after the user interacts with the page?

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
  .directive('setFocus', setFocus);

function setFocus($timeout, $parse) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var model = $parse(attrs.setFocus);
      scope.$watch(model, function(value) {
        if (value) {
          $timeout(function() {
            element[0].focus();
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };
}
```

An example of how I use this directive:

```
<div ng-show="parameter.repeatable" ng-repeat="index in parameter.values track by $index">
  <input
    name="parameter"
    type="text"
    ng-model="parameter.values[$index]"
    set-focus="$last">
    ...
```

As inputs are added to the page through user actions the focus jumps to the newest input. My problem is that on page load this action is not desired, only after the user begins interacting with the input fields.

Comment: if it's in a form could use the form object `$dirty` property for that element name. Not clear how you are using this

Comment: Please show us the DOM which triggers this directive

Comment: @charlietfl Edited my question to show how I use this directive.

Comment: You can manage it using a extra variable. Inside the link function, initialize a variable var init =0; then inside $watch function, check the `init` value. If it is 0, then ignore  `$timeout(function() { element[0].focus();});` . Finally increase `init` value to 1

Comment: really not clear what directive is supposed to do. `$last` won't change so no point in watching it. Also it is available in the scope of your `link` so don't really need it as attribute value either

Comment: @charlietfl It absolutely does change. Each time an input is added `$last` moves to that added input.

Comment: ok..so you are adding to array and want focus on last one when you add...I get it

Comment: is there a form? that would make it really easy , check if form is pristine or not. If there isn't one could use `ng-form` and do same

Comment: Why do you have this element in the DOM on pageload if it is added by user action?

Comment: or use a scope event when you add new item to array

Comment: @CharlieH The element is within an ng-repeat and there is always one of these elements on the page at page load.

Comment: create a simple demo in plunker

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround that might be suitable

In controller:

```
$scope.page ={first_load: true};
```

Directive:

```
function setFocus($timeout, $parse) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) { 
        if (!scope.page.first_load && $last) {
          $timeout(function() {
            element[0].focus();
          });
        }
         // last item of first rendering of `ng-repeat` will update controller 
         if(scope.page.first_load && $last){
            scope.page.first_load = false;
         }

      });
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Controller executes first and the first_load will anyway be true

Comment: @CharlieH correct, OP doesn't want this to activate first time. Only when items are added

Answer (score 0):

In your controller

```
$scope.loaded = false;
```

In your link function

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) { 
        if (!scope.$parent.loaded) {
            scope.$parent.loaded = true;
            return;
        }

        // Do the focusing here
}
```

Comment: won't work properly because `ng-repeat` creates child scope....will only change the current child scope. That's why I used an object for inheritance